I noticed someone Bluetooth a strange device to my iPad, how can I tell if they downloaded anything? Even if it’s hidden
I recently noticed that someone had Bluetooth into my new iPad. They disguise the device as my name plus Find My.* as an attempt to indicate that it was the Bluetooth necessary to use my device. I’ve recently dealt with numerous hacks and lost several Files photos, etc.. each time they access my iCloud they would remove things and add things. Therefore removing them from my device. I’m aware that you can hack a device through Bluetooth so how do I know if they downloaded anything to my device?

If you suspect people have access to your AppleID/iCloud account, change the password immediately and review your list of trusted devices. As for the Bluetooth topic mentioned above: Can you add some screenshots of the things you are describing by editing the question?
